# Rails Path Helper Does Not Rewrite URL In Location Bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, http-status-code-301

I have a route that redirects the root to `/welcome/about` correctly: `root to: redirect('/welcome/about')`

When I request `localhost:3000/` from my location bar, it redirects to `localhost:3000/welcome/about` as expected.

However, when I click on a link made with a path helper (e.g.`<%= link_to app_title, root_url %>`), *it does not change the URL in the location bar*.

Everything else works as expected. The link_to renders as `localhost:3000`, I get a 301 response with `Location: http://localhost:3000/welcome/about`, and the content is rendered from the correct template. I verified these results in Firefox and Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04.

Can anyone explain this browser behavior? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Please try this: `<%= link_to app_title, '/' %>`

Comment: Good suggestion, but I've tried `root_path`, `root_url`, `/` and just plain ol' `http://localhost:3000`. All with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a side-effect of turbolinks.

See: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/22

A little further digging reveals this issue was addressed by adding a `X-XHR-Redirected-To` header which turbolinks picks up on to reflect a redirect in the address bar.  It works when you call `redirect_to` in a controller, however it does not seem to work when redirecting root in routes.rb.  This smells like a bug so I created an issue: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/434

As a quick workaround you could add a `data-no-turbolink` attribute to the anchor tag (`<%= link_to app_title, root_url, data: {'no-turbolink' => true} %>`).  This would disable turbolinks for just that link.  Or you could use a named route helper that goes directly to /welcome/about.

Comment: Wow, spot on! I commented out turbolinks (and removed the javascript tag from application.html.erb), and the location bar reflected the new URL.

Any suggestions for workarounds? My current thought is a custom `root_path` helper that returns the `welcome_about_path` helper.

Comment: I updated my answer with a little more background on the issue and potential workarounds.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. I'm going with a root route for the about page and a named route for welcome_about that returns root_path.